# How to save/load the dark mode settings in the browser correctly with JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, darkmode

I've created dark mode for my website with HTML, CSS, and javascript.

here is my javascript code:

```js
var $jDarkMode = jQuery.noConflict();

$jDarkMode(document).ready(function($) {
    var darkModeToggle = $('#darkModeToggle');
    var body = $('body');

    var setDarkModePreference = function(value) {
        localStorage.setItem('darkMode', value);
    };

    var updateDarkMode = function() {
        var darkModePreference = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');

        if (darkModePreference === 'true') {
            body.addClass('dark-mode');
            darkModeToggle.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            body.removeClass('dark-mode');
            darkModeToggle.prop('checked', false);
        }
    };

    darkModeToggle.on('change', function() {
        if (darkModeToggle.prop('checked')) {
            body.addClass('dark-mode');
            setDarkModePreference(true);
        } else {
            body.removeClass('dark-mode');
            setDarkModePreference(false);
        }
    });

    updateDarkMode();
});
```

I tried to create a save statement. So if the user activates the dark mode once, it will be saved in the browser, and if the browser is closed or the page is refreshed, etc., because the dark mode has been activated before, the dark mode will be active.
But something is not working right.

It works in such a way that every time the page is loaded, it is first shown with the default light mode, and then the dark mode is activated.

It seems to stay for a few seconds and then the toggle button is pressed automatically and then dark is activated. And all this can be seen with the eyes!

Is it possible to save the settings in the browser so that as soon as the screen is loaded, the light screen will not be seen at all and the dark mode will be activated from the beginning and everything will be loaded with dark mode from the beginning? When it is saved, the movement of the toggle button can no longer be seen and it is saved in the same mode from the beginning.

Is my method wrong? I did not write the code correctly. Is this possible with JQuery/JavaScript, or is the language limited in this; And should we go to PHP?!

Comment: document.ready fires once the whole DOM has been built. You might want to find a way to execute your script earlier than that. The toggling of your checkbox will still have to wait until that element exists. But if you move the `dark-mode` class from `body` to `html`, then you can set it in the latter at pretty much any point, you could even do it directly from a script in the head, that doesn't delay by waiting for _any_ events at all.

Comment: `<script>document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark-mode', localStorage.getItem('darkMode')==='true');</script>` (`document.documentElement` accesses the root node, i.e. `html` in an HTML document.)

Comment: I read the description of that link and your comments, but I did not understand where the problem was or how should I use it. Can you make a modified version of my code?

Comment: _"but I did not understand where the problem was"_ - same explanation over there, as I already tried to give you here: The browser has already begun to apply styling, by the time your code executed only on document.ready, runs. So the solution, is to do the necessary stuff - setting of the dark mode trigger class - earlier, without waiting for that event to fire. I just explained how that can be done, and the duplicate has a slightly different variant, but it is basically the same principle.

Comment: can you check please `https://gist.github.com/paulvek/6e5f04d91e3e203a239f45ccba07454c` its ok now? or not?

Comment: Does it achieve what you want ...? If you are still starting with `var $jDarkMode = jQuery.noConflict();`, then this presumably gets embedded after a synchronous jQuery load, I suppose - which also costs time. (Which is why I already suggested, to place that part that sets the class, into a script element of its own, that you embed as early as possible.)

Comment: thanks. do I have to put that one line as pure JavaScript and out of no conflict and jQuery? To be implemented separately? Can the rest be in jQuery? Does this have a negative effect on the new conflict and the main code? for now, this is true and correct as your information? `https://gist.github.com/paulvek/bd8545b4bb4a36a93f085f3a6156723d` This does not affect the performance of other things and other JavaScript codes, and does it have any interference and conflict, speed reduction, and problems?

Comment: What I posted in my second comment, is what you should put separately, and as "high up" as possible (i.e, one of the first thing in `head`.) The rest can still be done later, and can use jQuery. (And you will have to modify your CSS, to make it dependent on this class set on `html`, not `body`. Or, if you want to keep it on body - change the code to use `document.body` then, and embed the script as first child of body.)

Comment: _"This does not affect the performance of other things and other JavaScript codes, and does it have any interference and conflict, speed reduction, and problems?"_ - the script inserted directly like that would be "render blocking" - but that will probably not cause too much of a noticeable effect. Or if it does, it will likely still be less annoying, than having the light mode styling flash up first.

Comment: can you check please its ok now? `https://gist.github.com/paulvek/78ec8d245b2a602a1ff6681527d03c5a` I write 3 codes with names my code, bard code, chatgpt code. can you tell me wich its better? and I use it?

Comment: Not going to do a code review for you now. Did you get it to work as intended? Then use whichever version achieved that. (Is all of that still supposed to be _one_ external script file? Then you have not implemented my suggestion yet, to move the setting of the class name to a place where it will execute "immediately" and without any delays?)